# How to create a chat Window

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am able to display the messages but through a table.
Can I use a textarea ? I don't know which controls to use.
I am new to MVC, any help would be appreciated.

```
<table class="table-responsive">
    <tr>
        <td id="output"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is my script:

```
function sendName(id) {
    $.ajax({   
        datatype: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: { 'senderName': id },
        url: '/Inbox/GetInboxes/',
        success: function (result)
        {
            debugger;
            let output = result.map(i => "<tr><td>" + i.FromID + "/" + i.Body + "/" + i.DateSent);
    
            $("#output").html(output);        
        },
        error: function (status, exception) 
        {
        //alert('Exception:', exception);
        }        
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`("#output").html(output)` - output is a `<td>` (table data) and you're adding a table row to it. The HTML structure should be `<table>` `<tr>` `<td>`.

Therefore you'll most likely want to add your `result` to the `<table>`

To illustrate this, I've produced a basic example where variable `result` it just a hard coded `array` (which looks like your data). Simply call `forEach` and call `append()` to add `<tr>` and `<td>` as string.

**As a simple example, try:**

Html:

```
<table  id="output" class="table-responsive">
</table>
```

Script:

```
$(function() {
  const result = [ 
    { FromID: "FromID 1", "Body" : "Body 1", "DateSent" : "1/1/2021" }, 
    { FromID: "FromID 2", "Body" : "Body 2", "DateSent" : "2/2/2021" }, 
  ]

  result.forEach(i => {
    $("#output").append("<tr><td>"  + i.FromID + "/" + i.Body + "/" + i.DateSent + "</td></tr>");
  });
});
```

See demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/dy3r0oqn/

There is not enough code to test your solutions. However you should be able to integrate the code with the following:

```
function sendName(id) {
    $.ajax({   
        datatype: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: { 'senderName': id },
        url: '/Inbox/GetInboxes/',
        success: function (result)
        {
             result.forEach(i => {
                $("#output").append("<tr><td>"  + i.FromID + "/" + i.Body + "/" + i.DateSent + "</td></tr>");
            });
        },
        error: function (status, exception) 
        {
           //alert('Exception:', exception);
        }        
    });
}
```